# How do I get the VR Scene Inspection add-on working with the Oculus Quest 2?

Tags: add-on, vr, oculus

I am obviously missing something and need some help. When I run the blender_oculus.cmd (located in the Blender 2.90 folder) then the Oculus software launches (installed properly) and Blender launches (VR Scene Inspection add-on previously enabled). I open my Blender scene and then, in the VR tab, I make sure the camera is properly set and click Start VR Session.

After doing all this, I put on the Quest 2, which is properly linked to my PC (everything setup correctly to the best of my knowledge) and nothing happens. My Blender scene does not appear through the headset.

Did I perform all the steps? At this point should I be seeing my scene or is there something else in the workflow that I have failed to do?

Thanks in advance for the help,
Bryson

Comment: i have the same trouble with my oculus quest 2 and blender. I can start a VR Session in Blender but if i put on my HMD there is just a loading screen from Blender in the VR Room[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq5Ov.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq5Ov.jpg)
It's loading but nothing happen. I use blender 2.90 and my HMD is connectet with USB to my PC.
All other applications from Steam in VR are working fine without any trouble. Greetings

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem but i could solve it.

1. Switch on your HMD
2. You have to plug in your HMD with USB to you PC
3. Start Oculus Link on your HMD
4. Usually it should start after starting Oculus link the oculus app on windows by itselfe
5. Now you can start your blender scene
6. Start VR-Session in Blender
7. Put on your HMD
8. Enjoy

Greetings